# Page not found 404

Tags: php, netbeans, web, localhost

I am beginner in PHP, and I am trying to run my first application, but it does not run and the browser opens "Not Found Page 404".

Any help for problem please?

Comment: Just a little question back: Do you know what the 404 error code means?

Comment: And another question back: Do you know that your webserver has a logfile exactly for these errors?

Comment: And it would be good for your question here if you outline how Netbeans is related to this. Are you also new to Netbeans?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that has been found by the OP already and is already finally solved.

Comment: I created the error! Haha. See my name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out are you in true directory?

You can check also apache error log to see path.

Comment: How can I see Apache error log ?

Comment: If you are using wamp you can find from %instalpath%\logs\apache_error.lpg
After that check out your apache httpd.conf what is your DocumentRoot path to compare. It will be inside %instalpath%\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Ok, Well I found the problem and finally I solve it

Answer (score -1):

You need to add more details... I don't think anyone can provide an answer to a question like this. What is the Url you tried to access? Are you sure you started the server?
Anyways try going to "localhost/"

Comment: Sure I can see you can not leave a comment because it needs 100 reputation. However, just by that fact, don't feel invited to leave an answer instead of a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Would you suggest a way that I could use to express myself in such a situation?

Comment: gain 100 reps. express yourself. (maybe not the answer you wanted to hear, sorry, but there is reason for that gap. 100 rep is easy to get).

Comment: For your info, it only needs 50 reps now. I guess it needed 100 in old days. I got them anyways and I'm ready to start expressing myself freely :)